# How to select multiple text fields with one javascript function on one onclick button?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I've been at this for hours now and searched countless forums. I would love some help on calling a function to apply to multiple text fields with a onclick button. Right now I have a working function that will select all text in a given text box and copy it to the clipboard. I need this function to be able to select all text in multiple boxes and copy it all at once with one click.

HTML text boxes

```
<form name="data_entry" id="data_frm" action="#">
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="3">

<tr><td>Root Cause:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="35" maxlength="250" name="cause" id="txt_cause">
</td></tr>

<tr><td>Actions Taken:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="35" maxlength="300" name="actions" id="txt_actions">
</td></tr>

<!--COPY BUTTON-->            
<td><input type="button" name="clipboard_copy" value="Copy" onClick="javascript:selectcopy('data_entry.caller')"></td>

</table>
</form>
```

And the Javascript code its calling is

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function selectcopy(fieldid)
{
var field=document.getElementById(fieldid) || eval('document.'+fieldid)
field.select()
if (field.createTextRange)
    {
    field.createTextRange().execCommand("Copy")
    }
}
```

So as it stands now, the copy button will copy the "caller" text field, but I need it to copy both (and many more fields) with one click. Also if possible, I need it to structure each text field on its own line when it copies so you can paste it and notice each line by itself? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And yes.. I do know there is no "caller" text field in my sample code, but if someone could show me how to copy both the "cause" and "actions" fields with one click, I would love them forever.

Comment: I assume you need all text from all text fields when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Get all the textfield values and concatenate them (use \n between fields to force newlines), and then use the execCommand on the resulting string.

Comment: Never thought of that, definitely makes sense though, Ill try it out and will see if its what I need when I get back to the office tomorrow!

Comment: Alright, I have it all concatenated in to one invisible text box in the exact format I want it in, now how do I get the onclick function to proecess this action first, and then use my javascript to select the box and copy it?

Comment: just call the concatenation action as the first line in your selectcopy function, and onclick call selectcopy with the id of your concatenated text box and leave the rest as it was.

Comment: The document.execCommand('copy') only works in IE. I believe it is blocked in all other browsers to prevent 'clipboard poisoning'.